# Detect if options have been entered in jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Does anyone know how to check if the called ui (custom) has also options input or using the defaults?

For example:

```
$('#selector').myUI();//does not have options.
$('#selector').myUI({option:'foo',{op:'bar'}});//ui has options.
$('#selector').myUI('value');//ui has options.
```

So if I was on:

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.myUI", {
       options = this.options;
       //check if options have been entered or the default values have been used?
    })

});
```

Comment: Question, why does it matter if options where entered?  It doesn't make sense to me...the widget should just obey either defaults or specified options and keep on going...if you explained more of what you're after, there might be a much simpler approach.

Comment: basically we can seperate the construction of the ui. check this url: exaplins  a bit more in details. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/help-detecting-options-if-they-have-been-entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether an option has been specified, you can write

```
if (options.hasOwnProperty('someProperty'))
```

Comment: you could do that as easy as saying `if(options.foo !='defaultValue')`
but since options are optional and can be entered in any order and can be Nth number of options it's not practical checking for each option. with if statements. If im not wrong. But thank you

Comment: this would make it slow... im raising this as an idea at jquery forum... because it should be very easy to be modified on it's core... e.g: getting the length of the "arguments.length" so hopefully they take that on bord. and it's only a one line the need to add .

Answer (score -1):

My guess is the only way to find out is to compare them against the default values.

But I'm not that familiar with the inner workings of jQuery.

Comment: have u had the need to use the option detector?